# WSO2 Application Server - REST Service, deploy as Application or Service?

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

If I have some functionality I want to expose via REST in the WSO2 Application Server and it seems that I have two main choices:

- Deploy as a JAX-RS **Application**
- Deploy as a **Service**

When deploying as a service, it appears that I have options for Quality of Service that don't appear to be available for Applications.

**Question**: If I am creating a REST based functionality from scratch, should I prefer to design as a service rather than as an application, because the service has more flexibility?

Comment: The Quality of Services available for (Axis2) services are only for SOAP operations. These can not be used for services exposed as REST. So, I guess JAX-RS would be the way to go since it's easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSO2 Application Server there are two approaches to create RESTfull services.

1. Create RESTfull service using Axis2, then you should deploy them as "service"
2. Create JAX-RS spec based service using CXF, then you should deploy them as "JAX-RS" applications.

Comment: if I don't have a strong preference either way for Axis2 or CXF, which one should I choose?  Axis2 seems to be better integrated with the WSO2 stack and easier to manage QoS features?  Are there any other benefits to deploying a service rather than an application?